# protractor | how to click a div with property of ng-click

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, dom, protractor

When trying to click on a div I keep getting `- Failed: element not visible`

```
Uitlis: openClosedSignElement(){
    $('[ng-click="changeViewToggle(category, taskSetProperty);isOpen = !isOpen"]').click();
}

e2e: it('Should add another task to template successfully', () =>  {
    taskUtils.openClosedSignElement();
}

tried also this inside Utilis: openClosedSignElement(){ 
    browser.element(by.id('addTaskTemplate')).click();
}
```

the Html

```
<div ng-show="header" id="closeSign" 
     class="closeSign"   ng-init="isOpen = isOpen ? isOpen : false"  
     ng-click="changeViewToggle(category, taskSetProperty);isOpen = !isOpen">
</div>
```

Comment: Share your HTML code

Comment: ` <div ng-show="header" id="closeSign" class="closeSign"   ng-init="isOpen = isOpen ? isOpen : false"  ng-click="changeViewToggle(category, taskSetProperty);isOpen = !isOpen"></div>`

Comment: you should update your question and calculation on html is not a good approach do it in controller.

Comment: the code is very complex in general I need to click the div if there is any example  it would be excellent

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve desired output by checking if element is displayed by `isDisplayed` else let click for example `head` element then continue your assertion

```
$('[ng-show=saving].icon-spin').isDisplayed().then(function(result) { //check whether element is displaye
  if (result) { //if yes go ahead
    $('[ng-click="changeViewToggle(category, taskSetProperty);isOpen = !isOpen"]').click();
  } else { //else by clickin relvent element make it display
    $("#header").click().then(function() {
        $('[ng-click="changeViewToggle(category, taskSetProperty);isOpen = !isOpen"]').click();
      }
    })
})
```

Comment: Hi thx for the quick comment,

can u please tell me what do i need to put inside  "[ng-show=saving].icon-spin'"